# Creating an API Gateway AWS Integration with S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I would like to set up API Gateway to retrieve files from a specific bucket on S3.

The `GET` method for the resource in the Cloudformation template looks like this:

```
GetMethod:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Method"
    Properties:
      HttpMethod: GET
      ApiKeyRequired: true
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      RequestParameters:
        'method.request.path.listId': true
      RestApiId:
        Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
      ResourceId:
        Ref: Lists
      Integration:
        Type: aws
        Credentials:
          Ref: S3ReadAccessRole
        IntegrationHttpMethod: GET
        PassthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_MATCH
        RequestParameters:
          'integration.request.path.key': 'method.request.path.listId'
```

I am having trouble specifying the S3 URI to integrate with. I've done the following with no success:

- The S3 URI: `arn:aws:s3:::lists/groceries/{key}`
- The API Gateway based uri based on [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-content-encodings-examples-image-s3.html). `arn:aws:apigateway:us-west-2:s3:lists/groceries/{key}`

Please help me figure out the correct URI to allow objects on S3 to be retrieved using API Gateway directly.

Comment: Your bucket name is lists?

Comment: @hephalump No it's not. It's more like `${myFirstName}${myLastName}Lists`. Using the name `lists` made more sense to me in the question as it's simpler.

Comment: Thats your issue... The ARN’s say the bucket name is “lists”. Put your proper ARNs and you’ll resolve your issue.

Comment: The ARN has been updated to use the name `lists` in the question as well. I just double checked this now.

Comment: Your bucket name is not “lists”... You have to put the actual bucket ARN of the bucket.